# Scriptures other than the Hata Yoga Pradipika containing asanas

Tags: yoga, asana, hatha-yoga

[chapter I](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/hyp/hyp03.htm) of Hata Yoga Pradipika lists out the following 15 different types of asanas along with details

> 1. Swastika-âsana,
> 2. Gomukha-âsana,
> 3. Vîrâsana,
> 4. Kurmâsana,
> 5. Kukkuṭa âsana,
> 6. Uttâna Kûrma-âsana,
> 7. Dhanura âsana,
> 8. Matsya-âsana,
> 9. Paśchima Tâna,
> 10. Mayûra-âsana,
> 11. Śava-âsana,
> 12. Siddhâsana,
> 13. Padmâsana,
> 14. Siṃhâsana and
> 15. Bhadrâsana

What are the scriptures that contain detail about any Hata yoga asanas **other than** that are mentioned in the Hata Yoga above.

Comment: Answer update as you were requiring the Asanas other than that mentioned in the list , i missed that part. :-)

Answer (score 4):

[Gheranda Samhita](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gheranda_Samhita)  is another text which describes Asanas and Mudras in details.  Along with Hatha Yoga Pradipika and Shiva Samhita, it is one the 3 classic treatises on Yoga.

The performance of Asanas is done in order to gain *Dhrirata* or firmness.

[image]

So, Asanas, Mudras etc are practiced as part of a larger Yogic procedure.

The 2nd Chapter of this text deals exclusively with Asanas and the 3rd with Mudras. Mudras given are also very similar to Asanas. For example, Viparatikarani, which is usually considered an Asana, is given under Mudras.

According to Gheranda Samhita there are 84 hundreds thousands Asanas as described by Lord Shiva. Of which only 84 are chief. Of which again only 32 are useful for us.

> Gheranda said ---- 1. There are 84 hundreds of thousands of Asanas
>   described by Shiva. The postures are as many as there are numbers of
>   species of living creatures in this universe.
>
> 2. Among them 84 are the best; and among these 84, 32 have been found useful for mankind in this world.

Then in the next few verses the names of these 32 Asanas are given:

[image]

So, the 32 Asanas like Padmasana, Bhadrasana, Swastikasana etc .. are mentioned and the procedures of forming them are also given in the subsequent portion of the chapter 2.

The PDF of the text can viewed from [here](http://hinduonline.co/DigitalLibrary/SmallBooks/GherandaSamhitaSanEng.pdf).

Answer (score 2):

**Yes** apart from Hatha Yoga Pradipika a text called [**The Yoga Yajnavalkya**](https://archive.org/details/YogaYajnavalkyaWithEnglishTranslationMohanA.G.2013/page/n39) is describing these asanas.  Yoga Yajnavalkya  is a dialog between well known Rishi Yajnavalkya  and Gargi a Brahmavadini.

Chapter three of Yoga Yajnavalkya  is describing list of eight asanas  in detail  with  procedure. These Asanas are **Svastikasana , Gomukhasana , Padmasana , Virasana ,Simhasana ,Bhadrasana ,Muktasana and Mayurasana.** As well as variations of these Asanas. I am posting some of them with shlokas.

> याज्ञवल्क्य उवाच : 
>  आसनान्यधुना वक्ष्ये शृणु गार्गि तपोधने ।
>   **स्वस्तिकं गोमुखं पद्मं वीरं सिंहासनं तथा ॥ १ ॥
>  भद्रं मुक्तासनं चैव मयूरासनमेव** च ।
>  तथैतेषां वरारोहे पृथग्वक्ष्यामि लक्षणम्
>   ॥२॥
>
> Yajnavalkya said  : Now i will describe the Asanas .Gargi rich in
>   austerity ,listen to me . Svastikasana , Gomukhasana , Padmasana ,
>   Virasana ,Simhasana ,Bhadrasana ,Muktasana and Mayurasana. I will
>   describe these asanas one by one .

---

Apart from asanas mentioned in Hata Yoga pradipika the Yoga Yajnavalkya is mentioning **Mukta Asana** which is not in the list.

## Muktasana

> सम्पीड्य सीवनीं सूक्ष्मां गुल्फेनैव तु सव्यतः ।
>  सव्यं
>   दक्षिणगुल्फेन मुक्तासनमितीरितम् मुक्तासनमितीरितम् ॥13॥
>
> Press the perineum by the left ankle  ,and the left ankle by right
>   ankle -this is known as Muktasana.

[image]

---

---

So [**Yoga-Yajnavalkya**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoga_Yajnavalkya) is describing  asanas apart from list given above.Here are [**Sanskrit**](https://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_yoga/yogayAjnyavalkya.pdf)  verses of 
Yoga Yajnavalkya